# $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} e^{-R^2 \cos(2t)} dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm trying to calculate $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} e^{-R^2 \cos(2t)} dt$. Here $R$ represents a continuous radius size, not a sequence (though I'm not sure if it matters). I am wishfully thinking that this integral will be $0$, because it would basically complete another calculation I'm doing on a homework problem if so and give me the right answer.

I know that if I can swap the limit and the integral I'll immediately get $0$. The thing is, I'm not confident I can do this. I don't think the inside is uniformly convergent; at $t = \frac{\pi}{4}$ I don't think it even goes to $0$.

Absent that, I'm mostly out of ideas, and I'd appreciate any thoughts people have.

Thanks!

Comment: You’re right, the sequence doesn’t converge uniformly. Since it’s a sequence of continuous functions, its limit would also be continuous if it were to converge uniformly.

Comment: Dominated Convergence Theorem gives the answer easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As *geetha290krm* says in the comments you can exchange the limit and the integral here using dominated convergence, but it's not necessary to use something so high-powered and a much simpler estimate suffices.

$\cos 2t$ is concave on the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$, so it lies above its secant line, which gives $\cos 2t \ge 1 - \frac{4t}{\pi}$. This gives

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} e^{-R^2 \cos 2t} \, dt &\le& \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} e^{-R^2 \left( 1 - \frac{4t}{\pi} \right)} \, dt \\
 &\le& \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^1 e^{-R^2 x} \, dx \\
 &\le& \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-R^2 x} \, dx \\
 &\le& \frac{\pi}{4 R^2} \end{eqnarray*}$$

where on the second line we use the substitution $x = 1 - \frac{4t}{\pi}$. Since the integral is non-negative it goes to zero as desired.